# Java applets with Safari on Windows as compared to Safari on OS X

Tags: java, testing, browser-compatibility

I have a developed an Applet which works fine on Chrome/IE/FF on Windows. I am not expecting any users for Safari on Windows but there might be the odd user who may be on a Mac.

As of now, I don't have a Mac to test my applet on.

I was wondering how similar is the behaviour of Safari on Windows is as compared to Safari on a Mac as far as Java Applets go. I was wondering if testing on Safari on Windows would be good enough or do I need to buy a Mac. I know that I can never be sure without actually testing on Mac, but I am on a tight budget for this and am willing to take a risk if it's not too big.

UPDATE: The applet accesses local devices.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Comment: @gnat - is it better now?

Comment: The most recent version of Safari for windows is 5. For Mac, it is 8. I doubt that safari 5 would be a sufficent test platform for a mac, especially since apple tends to be fairly good at getting people to upgrade os.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Safari browser for Windows is horribly outdated (the latest [download](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1531) is from May 9, 2012), it is not a reliable browser to use as test and compare with the Mac version. On a project I am working on, we found there where to many differences between the Mac / iPad version of safari and the Windows version, so we decided it was worth to buy a Mac (also for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right place for this question, but I am not sure.

However, you can use [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/). It gives you a VM of your desired OS/Browser to work with.

Comment: My applet needs access to a USB token which also installs drivers.